# Error in `[.data.frame`(data_for_analysis, , variable_name) : undefined columns selected in R

Tags: r

I am trying to use the TVEM-function to fit 'model1' using a dataset called 'databrandSpendPromo'. I want to fit the time-varying intercept of the varibale 'sum_value_sales_N'. The time-variable used is 'Date' and is in a Date-format, while 'sum_value_sales_N' is a numeric.

This code then throws an error:

```
model1 <- tvem(data=databrandSpendPromo,
     formula=sum_value_sales_N~1,
     time=Date)
```

```
'Error in `[.data.frame`(data_for_analysis, , variable_name) : undefined columns selected'
```

When I show traceback it says:

```
4.stop("undefined columns selected")

3.`[.data.frame`(data_for_analysis, , variable_name)

2.data_for_analysis[, variable_name]

1.tvem(data = databrandSpendPromo, formula = sum_value_sales_N ~ 1, time = Date)
```

It seems like R does not find the column 'sum_value_sales_N'.

I have also tried:

```
model1 <- tvem(data=databrandSpendPromo,
     formula=databrandSpendPromo$sum_value_sales_N~1,
     time=Date)
```

With the error:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(data_for_analysis, , variable_name) : undefined columns selected
```

And this:

```
model1 <- tvem(data=databrandSpendPromo,
     formula='sum_value_sales_N'~1,
     time=Date)
```

With the error:

```
Error in terms.formula(formula) : invalid term in model formula
```

Can you please help me understand what is wrong? The dataframe I am using looks just fine.

Comment: You said: `The dataframe I am using looks just fine`. You have to provide the dataframe or at least some sample of it which reproduces the error.

Comment: I am so sorry that I cannot share the data. If I could reproduce the problem, then I would most likely be able to fix it as well. I just needed some tips on what I should look for. Then I might be able to locate the specific error and reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is relatively old but if someone needs it...
I came across the same problem and the only thing that worked was to write the data frame exactly as they use it in the example: a column called "id", another "time", "x1", "x2",..., "y". I don't know why but after doing so, the function tvem worked.